# Getting rid of UILocalNotification on App Icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have a to do list app that sends notifications for specific chores. Everything works great but the red circle with the number of notifications never goes away on the icon. What kind of code should I add to get rid of those? Thanks!

Here is some code (it all works) just to give you the gist

Sending the notification...

```
- (void)sendNotification {

NSString *choreTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.chore.title];
NSString *choreDetail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.chore.detail];

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotification) {
    localNotification.fireDate = self.datePicker.date;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;
    localNotification.soundName = @"bell_tree.mp3";
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"A friendly reminder, %@, %@", choreTitle, choreDetail];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = self.datePicker.date;
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"An alert will be sent to you on %@",formattedDateString] message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay!" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}]];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In the app delegate...

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];
}
}
```

Comment: `UIApplication` does have `cancelNotificaton:` and `cancelAllNotifications`. Are you looking for that or for `setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:`?

Comment: Perhaps that's it, I'm not sure though, whatever gets rid of them after the app has been opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Inside your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and/or `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: Okay so at first on the simulator I thought this worked but now that my app is available again (with this code in the app delegate) it's still showing an icon with the number 1. I wonder what else it could be?

Comment: Is it in both methods and are you not sending local notifications white the app is active?